# Changing the origin of the coordinate system aligned on an image when using the ImageFowardTransformation function

Tags: image-processing, code-request

When using the image transformation command

`ImageFowardTransformation[image, function]` the pixels of the image you input are in cartesian coordinates that by default are aligned with the bottom left hand corner of every 2d image.

If I want to shift the origin to the centre (from that default settings) which command would I put inside the transformation command?

Comment: Did you remember to set `DataRange` and `PlotRange` accordingly?

Comment: I did put `DataRange -> Full` but I thought `DataRange` just tells you the range of data values (pixels) you want to transform but not sure if that's the same as actually shifting the default origin of the coordinate system from the bottom left corner of the image to the center.

Comment: This question is related to one of my other pending questions "Using a numerical table in the form of an interpolating function inside the ImageTransformation command" still need to update that with my current thoughts though

Comment: do you get what you need using the options `DataRange->Full` and  `PlotRange -> Transpose@{function@{0, 0}, function@ImageDimensions[image]}`?

Comment: `DataRange -> Full` - ah, that's the lazy route. If you need to control the transformation domain, you need to specify explicit ranges. Have a look at this example: `img = Rasterize[Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3]]; ImageForwardTransformation[img, AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[Pi/6], {2, 1}}], DataRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure actually since I am trying to get the functions inside the `ImageForwardTransformation` to work but does that command you gave shift the origin of the coordinate system used to define each pixel {x,y} in the image to the center of that image? When I mean shift I just mean reassign the origin from the bottom LHS of every image to be centered in the middle of the image. If so I think it should work